# Print elements when the difference is greater/lesser than a condition in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

in a numpy array , I have to print out elements when the difference between elements is > or < 1
Basically it should print the element when the difference is > or < 1

```
Input : arr=np.array([1, 3, 3,4,7,4,1,6,7,8,9,5,13])
Output: 3,7,4,1,6,5,13
```

This is what I tried , but then it does not give correct output . Any pointers would be helpful

```
arr=np.array([1, 3, 3,4,7,4,1,6,7,8,9,5,13])
z=np.diff(arr) 

list=[]
for a in arr:
    for q in z:
        if q > 1:
            list1.append(arr1[a])
            print(arr[q+1])
```

Comment: This does not produce *any* output, as it has errors.

Comment: Hi , My bad I mean to say it should print the element when the difference between the neighboring elements is greater than 1 or less than -1 .                                                                                                                                               Input : arr=np.array([1, 3, 3,4,7,4,1,6,7,8,9,5,13])
Output: 3,7,4,1,6,5,13

Comment: Your expected output should contain the first `1` from the original array (as my result below does) because the difference between that and its next element (`3`) is greater than one.

Comment: "I have to print out elements when the difference between elements is > or < 1 " - the difference between **which** elements? Why are we using Numpy for this task? Do we actually need to consider the case of more than one dimension in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using numpy already, try not to loop over the array -- by doing so, you ignore the wonderful ability of numpy to perform fast operations that work on the entire array instead of element-by-element.

You can create a boolean array called `discard_elements`, which will contain `True` if it is to be discarded, i.e. the difference between corresponding element of `arr` and the previous element is less than or equal to one. First, initialize it to be all `False`

```
discard_elements = np.zeros_like(arr, dtype=bool)
```

Next, calculate the locations where the [absolute value](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) of the [difference between consecutive elements](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) of the array is less than or equal to one.
Assign these values to the slice of `discard_elements` beginning at the `1` index, because the `0`th index doesn't have any elements before it.

```
discard_elements[1:] = (np.abs(np.diff(arr)) <= 1)
```

Finally, use the inverse of this boolean array to mask the original:

```
result = arr[~discard_elements]
```

This gives the desired `result`:

```
array([ 1,  3,  7,  4,  1,  6,  5, 13])
```

Note that your expected output should contain the first `1` from the original array (as my `result` does) because the difference between that and its next element (`3`) is greater than one.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, really. You can use indexing to get the next element. You can use `zip(arr, arr[1:])` to get all consecutive pairs, and then you need to check the difference between the pairs, you are looking for the second element when the absolute difference is greater than 1.

The following code gives what you want:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([ 1,  3,  3,  4,  7,  4,  1,  6,  7,  8,  9,  5, 13])

for a, b in zip(arr, arr[1:]):
    if abs(a - b) > 1:
        print(b)
```

```
3
7
4
1
6
5
13
```

In NumPy:

```
arr[1:][np.abs(arr[1:] - arr[:-1]) > 1]
```

```
array([ 3,  7,  4,  1,  6,  5, 13])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean indexing on with the results of `np.diff` on the array

```
arr = np.array([1, 3, 3, 4, 7, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 13])

z = np.diff(arr)
print(arr[1:][(z > 1) | (z < -1)])
# or
print(arr[1:][np.abs(z) > 1])
```

Output

```
[ 3  7  4  1  6  5 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the elements of a numpy array where the difference between adjacent elements is greater or less than 1, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 3, 3, 4, 7, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 13])
diff_arr = np.diff(arr) # Calculate the differences between elements adjacent

result = []

# Iterates through the elements of the numpy array
for i in range(len(diff_arr)):
    if abs(diff_arr[i]) > 1:  # Check if the difference is greater than 1
        result.append(arr[i + 1])  # Adds the next element to the result

print(result)
```

This will print elements whose differences from adjacent elements are greater than 1. The result will be [3, 7, 4, 1, 6, 5, 13], which is as expected according to your description.

Here, np.diff(arr) is used to calculate the differences between adjacent elements, and then we check whether these differences are greater than 1 to determine which elements should be printed.